# Why do we call exit function in php when downloading using readfile function

Tags: php

Below is the code snippet that forces a download using readfile function:

```
<?php
  if($type == 1){
      $path = "assets/images/katiba.pdf";
  }else if($type == 2){
      $path = "assets/images/katiba2.pdf";
  }else if($type == 3){
      $path = "assets/images/katiba3.pdf";
  }

  if (file_exists($path)) {
      header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
      header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($path).'"');
      header('Expires: 0');
      header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
      header('Pragma: public');
      header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
      readfile($path);
      exit;
  }
?>
```

Please why do we call exit function at the end. Help please!

Comment: remove `exit` and `echo "something";` after header and check what happend ?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no code following after it, it's actually safe to remove this. If however you have shutdown handlers running etc, then this just tells php to stop right there and not bother running any more code.

Answer (score 0):

It terminates execution of the script.  Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

exit is a language construct and it can be called without parentheses if no status is passed.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php for more information